# Pandas: Group and count [Refunded] and [Cancelled] orders into one?

Tags: python, pandas

There I have a table loaded into DataFrame as:

| Date | OrderId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | 1 | Successful |
| 2021-05-02 | 2 | Successful |
| 2021-05-03 | 3 | Refunded |
| 2021-05-03 | 4 | Cancelled |
| 2021-05-05 | 5 | Refunded |

I am going to count how many orders succeed and failed for each date. For the [Cancelled] and [Refunded] status orders, they are considered [Failed].

Expected result:

| Date | Succeed Orders | Failed Orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-02 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 0 | 2 |
| 2021-05-05 | 0 | 1 |

How do I get this result via pandas?

```py
df.groupby(['Date','Status']).size()  

#  then?
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.value_counts`:

```
df["Status"] = df["Status"].map({"Successful": "Succeed Orders"}).fillna("Failed Orders")
new_df = df.groupby("Date")["Status"].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
Status      Failed Orders  Succeed Orders
Date                                     
2021-05-01              0               1
2021-05-02              0               1
2021-05-03              2               0
2021-05-05              1               0
```

Answer (score 1):

use `pd.crosstab()`+`replace()`:

```
out=(pd.crosstab(df['Date'],df['Status'].replace({'Refunded':'Failed','Cancelled':'Failed'}))
       .rename_axis(columns=None).add_suffix(' Orders').reset_index())
```

output:

```
    Date       Failed Orders    Successful Orders
0   2021-05-01  0               1
1   2021-05-02  0               1
2   2021-05-03  2               0
3   2021-05-05  1               0
```